# How to filter based on property value in an array of objects in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have an input text that takes the area as show below:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="areaSearch">
```

And, i have a list to filter based on the entered area against `area_name` property

```
<ul *ngIf="areaSearch">
    <li *ngFor="let area of areaList | filter : {area_name: areaSearch} ">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Am getting error like `The pipe 'filter' could not be found`. Can anyone help me to solve this?..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular does not have concept named **`filter`**, instead you should create your **`custom pipe`** as follows,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'filterByArea'})
export class FilterByStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(areaList : any, areaname: string): any[] {
        if (areaList) {
            return areaList.filter((listing: any) => listing.area_name === areaname);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as follows,

```
<ul *ngIf="areaSearch">
    <li *ngFor="let area of areaList | filterByArea:areaSearch">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can't we do this in view itself like we do in AngularJs?

Comment: no you cannot do, because angualr2 does not support filters

Comment: well its a nice solution and i don't know who downvoted your answer :-\

Comment: @Sajeetharan I didn't downvote, but I think I know why it happened. You posted a partial answer without any supporting code or explanation first right? The voter probably saw your post in that state, before you fleshed out the answer with more helpful details.

Comment: @BeetleJuice No indeed i posted with example first

Comment: @Sajeetharan ok.  By the way where does `listings` in your `transform()` come from?  Do you mean `areaList`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice yes could be because of that :) corrected now! thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4):

I would define `filteredAreaList` in the component as a readonly:

```
// this goes in the component
get filteredAreaList() {
    return this.areaList.filter(v => v.area_name === this.areaSearch)
}
```

This will ensure that `filteredAreaList` has only those elements of `areaList` whose `area_name` property matches the current `areaSearch`

Then in the template, just iterate over `filteredAreaList`

```
<ul *ngIf="areaSearch">
    <li *ngFor="let area of filteredAreaList ">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

One benefit of this approach is that the logic is kept out of the template, and it is easy to extend (e.g: if in the future the displayed list depends on other component properties). I also like the pipe solution from Sajeetharan.

**UPDATE: 2019-05-17**

With nearly 2 more yrs of Angular under my belt since I wrote my answer, I have a slightly new perspective upon reading mine and Sajeetharan's accepted response.  My solution has less overhead; it is also easier to implement; there are fewer steps -- no need to create a pipe, declare it in a module, make sure the component's module also has access to it etc.  However Sajeetharan's solution will run faster especially if `areaList` is a big array because by default the pipe logic is only run if the inputs change.

This means that in practice once the user enters an area name, the filter will execute just once and be done, whereas with my solution, the `filteredAreaList` getter will execute every change detection cycle.  The difference is trivial if you have only a few dozen areas, but if you have a very large set it matters.

Comment: can't we do this in view itself like we do in AngularJs?